# How to focus a invisible item in lazyColumn on jetpackCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to scroll the `lazyColumn` when its child get focused.

I use `rememberLazyListState`'s `scrollToItem` method to scroll the `lazyColumn`.

[image]

but when a item at top been scrolled out, it can't be focused again.

[image]

[image]

My sample code:

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableList(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    LazyColumn(
        state = scrollState,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)
    ) {

        itemsIndexed(items = (0..10).toList()) { index, item ->
            FocusableBox(
                title = "ScrollBox-$index",
                onFocused = { focused ->
                    scope.launch {
                        if (focused) {
                            scrollState.scrollToItem(index)
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FocusableBox(
    title: String,
    onFocused: (Boolean) -> Unit = {},
    requester: FocusRequester = FocusRequester(),
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var boxColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.White) }
    var focused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .focusRequester(requester)
            .onFocusChanged {
                boxColor = if (it.isFocused) Color.Green else Color.Gray
                focused = it.isFocused
                onFocused(it.isFocused)
            }
            .focusable()
            .background(boxColor)
            .zIndex(if (focused) 1f else 0f)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = title,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(30.dp),
            color = Color.White,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this Article, https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/focus-in-jetpack-compose-6584252257fe

Comment: Please whenever you paste sample code, remove the unnecessary stuff like decorations and layout positioning. Provide only necessary stuff to highlight and analyse the problem in concern. It increases your chances of the question being answered.

Answer (score 2):

add

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
```

then after child been focused, use `scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` to determine scroll up or scroll down.

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableList(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    LazyColumn(
        state = scrollState,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)
    ) {

        itemsIndexed(items = (0..10).toList()) { index, item ->
            FocusableBox(
                title = "ScrollBox-$index",
                onFocused = { focused ->
                    scope.launch {
                        if (focused) {
                            val visibleItemsInfo = scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
                            val visibleSet = visibleItemsInfo.map { it.index }.toSet()
                            if (index == visibleItemsInfo.last().index) {
                                scrollState.scrollToItem(index)
                            } else if (visibleSet.contains(index) && index != 0) {
                                scrollState.scrollToItem(index - 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```