# Jetpack Compose LazyRow - Center selected item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

How can I calculate the position of the selected item in a LazyRow and use it for centering the item on the screen?
The items will have various sizes depending on their content.

If I go with `lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(index)` the selected item will be positioned to the left in the LazyRow.
[image: Result]

What I want to achieve is to have the selected item centered like this
[image: Expected]

The code I have currently:

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Column {
        TestRow(listOf("Angola", "Bahrain", "Afghanistan", "Denmark", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Fiji", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", "Kuwait", "Laos", "Mongolia"))
        TestRow(listOf("Angola", "Bahrain", "Afghanistan"))
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalSnapperApi::class)
@Composable
fun TestRow(items: List<String>) {
    val selectedIndex = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        state = lazyListState,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 12.dp),
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapperFlingBehavior(
            lazyListState = lazyListState,
            snapOffsetForItem = SnapOffsets.Start
        )
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->
            TestItem(
                content = item,
                isSelected = index == selectedIndex.value,
                onClick = {
                    selectedIndex.value = index
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(index)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestItem(
    content: String,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = if (isSelected) Color.Green else Color.Yellow,
            contentColor = Color.Black
        ),
        elevation = null,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        onClick = onClick
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 10.dp),
            text = (content).uppercase(),
        )
    }
}
```

The code `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.CenterHorizontally)` is to make sure the LazyRow centers all the items, when there is not enough items for scrolling.
Example with 3 items:
[image: All centered]

I have tried various suggestions posted at similar questions, but with no luck in finding a solution.
[jetpack-compose-lazylist-possible-to-zoom-the-center-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832396/jetpack-compose-lazylist-possible-to-zoom-the-center-item)
[how-to-focus-a-invisible-item-in-lazycolumn-on-jetpackcompose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931565/how-to-focus-a-invisible-item-in-lazycolumn-on-jetpackcompose)
[/jetpack-compose-make-the-first-element-in-a-lazyrow-be-aligned-to-the-center-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71838922/jetpack-compose-make-the-first-element-in-a-lazyrow-be-aligned-to-the-center-o)

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution that fits my needs, since I don't expect to navigate to a selected item, without being able to see it.

This solution can't center items that is not visible on the screen.

```
coroutineScope.launch {
  val itemInfo = lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index }
  if (itemInfo != null) {
     val center = lazyListState.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset / 2
     val childCenter = itemInfo.offset + itemInfo.size / 2
     lazyListState.animateScrollBy((childCenter - center).toFloat())
  } else {
     lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(index)
  }
}
```

Hope t

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.  Works as expected.  It's genius, but I can't help but feel that there must be an easier way...

Answer (score 6):

Improving the @Markram answer

You can create an extension of "LazyListState":

```
fun LazyListState.animateScrollAndCentralizeItem(index: Int, scope: CoroutineScope) {
    val itemInfo = this.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index }
    scope.launch {
        if (itemInfo != null) {
            val center = this@animateScrollAndCentralizeItem.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset / 2
            val childCenter = itemInfo.offset + itemInfo.size / 2
            this@animateScrollAndCentralizeItem.animateScrollBy((childCenter - center).toFloat())
        } else {
            this@animateScrollAndCentralizeItem.animateScrollToItem(index)
        }
    }
}
```

And then just use it directly in your Composable:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
coroutineScope.launch {
    listState.animateScrollAndCentralizeItem(index , this)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Improving both Soares and Markman answers you can reference the methods without this for readability and make the function suspend instead of passing a coroutine scope.

```
suspend fun LazyListState.animateScrollAndCentralizeItem(index: Int) {
    val itemInfo = this.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index }
    if (itemInfo != null) {
        val center = layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset / 2
        val childCenter = itemInfo.offset + itemInfo.size / 2
        animateScrollBy((childCenter - center).toFloat())
    } else {
        animateScrollToItem(index)
    }
}
```

Then you can just call it as you'd normally call animateScrollToItem

```
scope.launch {
    lazyListState.animateScrollAndCentralizeItem(index)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version that works on off-screen items. Because the animation is fast, the flash is hard to notice.

A more perfect but complex solution is to use `scroll { ... }` to control the whole animation as `animateScrollToItem` does.

```
suspend fun LazyListState.centerItem(index: Int) {
    suspend fun locateTarget(): Boolean {
        val layoutInfo = layoutInfo
        val containerSize =
            layoutInfo.viewportSize.width - layoutInfo.beforeContentPadding - layoutInfo.afterContentPadding

        val target = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index }
            ?: return false
        val targetOffset = containerSize / 2f - target.size / 2f
        animateScrollBy(target.offset - targetOffset)
        return true
    }

    if (!locateTarget()) {
        val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
        val currentIndex = visibleItemsInfo.getOrNull(visibleItemsInfo.size / 2)?.index ?: -1
        scrollToItem(
            if (index > currentIndex) {
                (index - visibleItemsInfo.size + 1)
            } else {
                index
            }.coerceIn(0, layoutInfo.totalItemsCount)
        )
        locateTarget()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean solution:

```
suspend fun LazyListState.animateScrollToItemCenter(index: Int) {
    layoutInfo.resolveItemOffsetToCenter(index)?.let {
        animateScrollToItem(index, it)
        return
    }

    scrollToItem(index)

    layoutInfo.resolveItemOffsetToCenter(index)?.let {
        animateScrollToItem(index, it)
    }
}

private fun LazyListLayoutInfo.resolveItemOffsetToCenter(index: Int): Int? {
    val itemInfo = visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index } ?: return null
    val containerSize = viewportSize.width - beforeContentPadding - afterContentPadding
    return -(containerSize - itemInfo.size) / 2
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

LaunchedEffect(selectedIndex) {
    lazyListState.animateScrollToItemCenter(selectedIndex)
}
// Or use rememberCoroutineScope() instead
```